# Giving different names to a html object in a loop in PHP

Tags: php

How would I be able to give the different  things different names (as I am creating them in a loop) so that I can use the data? Could I modify name=\"type\" to maybe include $x within the name so that it is different each time?

```
For($x=0; $x<=$noQuestions-1; $x++){

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>"."Question ".($x+1).": ".$question[$x]."</tr>";
    echo "<form method=\"post\">";
    echo "<Select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"type\" required>";
    echo "<option value=\"1\">".$optionData[$x][0]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"2\">".$optionData[$x][1]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"3\">".$optionData[$x][2]."</option>";
    echo "<option value=\"4\">".$optionData[$x][3]."</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Did you try? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply concatenate variable $x in name like this:

```
echo "<Select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"type".$x."\" required>";
```

**EDIT:**

```
$type = "dropdown";
for($x=0; $x<=$noQuestions-1; $x++)
{
       echo "<table>";
       echo "<tr>"."Question ".($x+1).": ".$question[$x]."</tr>";
       echo "<form method=\"post\">";
       echo "<Select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"".$type.$x."\" required>";
       echo "<option value=\"1\">".$optionData[$x][0]."</option>";
       echo "<option value=\"2\">".$optionData[$x][1]."</option>";
       echo "<option value=\"3\">".$optionData[$x][2]."</option>";
       echo "<option value=\"4\">".$optionData[$x][3]."</option>";
       echo "</select>"; echo "</form>";
       echo "</table>";

 }
```

Comment: I am only able to get $type0 for some reason when echoing it.

Comment: if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
        extract($_REQUEST);
  
  if ($_POST['dropdown0']=="1") {
   echo "1";
  } elseif ($_POST['dropdown0']=="2") {
   echo "2";
  } elseif ($_POST['dropdown0']=="3") {
   echo "3";
  } elseif ($_POST['dropdown0']=="4") {
   echo "4";
  }
  
  if ($_POST['dropdown1']=="1") {
   echo "1";
  } elseif ($_POST['dropdown1']=="2") {
   echo "2";
  } elseif ($_POST['dropdown1']=="3") {
   echo "3";
  } elseif ($_POST['dropdown1']=="4") {
   echo "4";
  }
 }

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do...can you please elaborate?...I tried the answer which I have given, and it's type0, type1, etc are coming.

Comment: I am making a multiple choice quiz player. I have already created a test maker so the number of questions in the quiz player depends. So I have a html form within a php loop to create a certain amount of questions and options. Did you echo it in a different way than I did? Could you show me please

Comment: I guess you are creating type a variable. If this is the case, then do it like this: $type = "dropdown";  & in place of name: name=\"".$type.$x."\"

Comment: It is still only allowing me to get "dropdown0" as a variable. I really don't know why. You said you tried it and it worked? Could you show me?

Answer (score 0):

One  simple solution  would be to add $x in the name like this for example:

`echo "< select class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"type-$x\" required>";`

Comment: how would i echo the variable in regular PHP? Would it be "echo $type-0";

Comment: It depends on how you submit the fields. If your form method is "post" then you will echo the variable with $_POST ["type-0"], if your form method is "get" you will use $_GET ["type-0"]